# How to slow down Snake game transition from moving right to moving down with SDL2?

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

im making a Snake game in C++ with SDL2. When the snake moves towards the right and the user presses the down arrow key, im removing the tail and adding a new head like this:

```
void SnakeGame::TransitionDown() {
    for (SnakePart snakePart : parts) {
        RemoveTail();
        NewHead();
    }
    direction = 3;
} 

void SnakeGame::RemoveTail() {
    parts.erase(parts.end() - 1);
}

void SnakeGame::NewHead() {
    SnakePart sp;
    sp.LoadPart(GameWindow, GameRenderer, GetHeadXPosition(), GetHeadYPosition() + 18);
    parts.insert(parts.begin(), sp);
}
```

If i put a for loop inside the TransitionDown() function and increment it just a portion of the snake size, i can see that it transitions the way i want - just that its doing it way too fast! Is there any way i can remove the tail and add a new head, and then wait abit before repeating?

Comment: Modifying `parts` while iterating over them most likely is Undefined Beavior.

Comment: I know, but that is not my question :D I have made it work somehow :))

Comment: Check your platform to see if it has a `sleep` or `delay` function.

Comment: You could use nested `for` loops to create a delay.